# How to get Facebook profile picture from Android App?

Tags: android, facebook

I have created a simple test App on android with "login with facebook".

This is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView info;
    private LoginButton loginButton;
    private CallbackManager callbackManager;

    String email;
    String birthday;
    String name;
    String gender;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

        info = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.fb_text);
        loginButton = (LoginButton)findViewById(R.id.fb_login);
        loginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("public_profile", "email", "user_birthday"));


        loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                info.setText(
                        "User ID: "
                                + loginResult.getAccessToken().getUserId()
                                + "\n" +
                                "Auth Token: "
                                + loginResult.getAccessToken().getToken()
                );

                GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                        loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                        new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                                Log.v("LoginActivity", response.toString());

                                // Application code
                                try {
                                    email = object.getString("email");
                                    birthday = object.getString("birthday"); // 01/31/1980 format
                                    name = object.getString("name");
                                    gender = object.getString("gender");
                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }

                                info.append(
                                        "User Name: " + name
                                                + "\n" +
                                                "birthday: "
                                                + birthday
                                                + "\n" +
                                                "Gender: "
                                                + gender
                                                + "\n" +
                                                "Email: "
                                                + email
                                );
                            }
                        });
                Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,email,gender,birthday");
                request.setParameters(parameters);
                request.executeAsync();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                info.setText("Login Cancelled");

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException e) {
                info.setText("Login Failed");
            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

What should i do to get the profile picture of the user and show it into the my activity?

Comment: Use facebook api:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/picture/

Comment: use this:"https://graph.facebook.com/"+id of fbuser+"/picture?type=large"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just add the following parameter in your existing code

```
parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,email,gender,birthday,picture.type(large)");
```

picture.type(large) will return URL with your profile picture

By the way you can get that URL from JSONObject returned by facebook like this:

```
profilePicUrl = object.getJSONObject("picture").getJSONObject("data").getString("url");
```

Answer (score 3):

get facebook_id of loggedIn user by

```
name = object.getString("name");
facebook_id = object.getString("id");
```

**FIRST METHOD**

Use use `ProfilePictureView` in place of `ImageView`

```
<com.facebook.login.widget.ProfilePictureView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
```

And set ProfilePic using facebook_id to this by this line

```
profilePictureView.setProfileId(facebook_id);
```

**SECOND METHOD**

Get Bitmap of User profile pic using facebook_id and set this Bitmap to ImageView.

```
URL img_value = new URL("https://graph.facebook.com/" + facebook_id + "/picture?type=large");

Bitmap mIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(img_value.openConnection().getInputStream());
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this get the id of fb user and then get the profile pic by that id.

```
 GraphRequest request = new GraphRequest(
                AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                "/me",
                null,
                HttpMethod.GET,
                new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                    public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
           /* handle the result */
                        try {
                            Logs.log(TAG, response.getJSONObject().toString());
                            String id = response.getJSONObject().getString("id");
                            String email = response.getJSONObject().getString("email");
                            String name = response.getJSONObject().getString("name");

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            Logs.log(e);
                        }
                    }
                }
        );
        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
        parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,email");
        request.setParameters(parameters);
        request.executeAsync();
```

Then profile pic of user will be at:-

```
"https://graph.facebook.com/"+id of user+"/picture?type=large"
```